# How can I set the default file name in saveFileDialog.SetFilename in wxPython for windows?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

For some reason, the following code snippet works on OS X Mavericks, but not on Windows 7:

```
fileLabelDefault = self.filename + ".xlsx"
saveFileDialog = wx.FileDialog(self, "Speichern", "", fileLabelDefault, 
                                   "Excel files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx", 
                                   wx.FD_SAVE | wx.FD_OVERWRITE_PROMPT)
saveFileDialog.SetFilename(fileLabelDefault)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to answer this question myself, because I just figured out the answer!

The code above is valid. I had an invalid character `/` in the default filename and OS X allows this, but replaces it with a `:`. Windows does not do this automatically.